# Flutter "import framework:dart" throws error

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, frameworks

my Flutter dart script requires 'import framework:dart'. But Visual Studio Code's "Problems Tab" indicates this error:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'framework:dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.
```

Needing suggestions to remedy this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the flutter framework for dart, the import must be:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

if you want to use the Cupertino-style (==iOS theme) than you have to make following import:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

If you have Flutter installed, this imports should work.

Comment: thanks for the instruction. i'll see which one of these is best for me.. stay tuned

Answer (score 0):

Because `framework.dart` is in the `widgets.dart` library packages, I think you need to import the `widgets.dart` library.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
```

For the usage, you can read the docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/widgets-library.html).
I hope it will help.